# Is Kafka Streams library v1.1.0 forward compatible with Kafka cluster v2.8.1?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, compatibility, kafka-producer-api

I'm running a Kafka Streams application. Here's the current version compatibility:

- kafka-streams v1.1.0 (with custom changes on top of it)
- kafka cluster v2.1.1

I'm planning to upgrade my Kafka cluster to v2.8.1. Is the same kafka-streams library compatible with the newer kafka version? I'm not able to find any official compatibility matrix for streams. I could find one from [Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/introduction.html#ak), but none from the official Kafka website.

I ran my Kafka Streams app against Kafka v2.8.1 and it does seems to run. I'd like to avoid any surprises at a later point in time, hence looking for any pointers to compatibility or support.

Answer (score 2):

The Kafka Streams API uses the Kafka consumer and producer API underneath. The Kafka protocol is backward compatible so you should not have any problem (so having new Kafka cluster working with old Kafka clients).
Takes only into account that starting with Kafka 4.0.0 (not released yet), they are planning to remove this backward compatibility. See KIP-896 for more details here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-896%3A+Remove+old+client+protocol+API+versions+in+Kafka+4.0